# Why is it not possible to combine data-dismiss="alert" and input type = submit on one input type button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following line of code which should send a post request

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name = "accept" value = "Akzeptieren" data-dismiss="alert">
```

but it does not work until i remove data-dismiss="alert"

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name = "accept" value = "Akzeptieren">
```

why is it not working and is there any way so i can use them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the handle that caught the event is stopping the event. Thus, the form submit event does not occur.

#### [bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js#L345](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6ffb0b48e455430f8a5359ed689ad64c1143fac2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js#L345)

[image: bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js]

I think you can overcome this with a logic like the following.

- Specifying a private selector (`data-dismiss="alert&submit"`)
- To catch the clicks on our selector, close the "`alert`" and allow the `form|submit` event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-dismiss="alert&submit"]').on('click', function() {
    $('.alert').alert('close');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<form>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="accept" value="Akzeptieren" data-dismiss="alert&submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i've copied your code 1:1 and it doesnt work, even though it works here on the stackoverflow website. Do <script> tags belong in the header or body?

Comment: oops I'm just dumb, got it working now, my cookie name was different, thank you

Comment: @Nico1300 All right. Glad it was okay. Good luck with